# What is the "hope" talked about in Hebrews 10:23

Tags: greek, word-study, hebrews, historical-interpretation, authorial-intent

> [Hebrews 10:23](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/10-23.htm) Let us hold fast the confession of our **hope** without
>   wavering, for he who promised is faithful.

What is the hope referred into in the above verse?

Is this the same hope talked about in

> [Hebrews 6:19](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/6-19.htm) We have this as a sure and steadfast anchor of the
>   soul, a **hope** that enters into the inner place behind the curtain,

How does this hope become an anchor of the soul?

Is John also talking about the same hope?

> [1 John 3:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%203&version=KJV) King James Version (KJV) 3 Behold, what manner of
>   love the Father hath bestowed upon us, that we should be called the
>   sons of God: therefore the world knoweth us not, because it knew him
>   not.2 Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear
>   what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be
>   like him; for we shall see him as he is. 3 And every man that hath
>   this **hope** in him purifieth himself, even as he is pure.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, as it is used in Greek is really more of an expectation or anticipation of a sure thing. In English, a hope may or may not happen. So I prefer to substitute “expectation” in almost every case.

> The short answer is “Christ in you folks is the expectation of glory,”
>   **as in the glory cloud filling God’s habitation.**

Right at the beginning of Hebrews, we learn the reality is “in Son” (Heb 1:2 when the extra-added words are removed). Then Heb 1:3 explains the **Image of the Son.**

By the time we get to Heb 10, the beginning of the chapter talks about “a body you have prepared for Me” (Heb 10:5). This is about the “True Temple” **that we are** all being built into as spiritual stones. Again, the expectation is Christ within you people, the expectation of His glory filling His temple / **body that we are.**

Then in Heb 10:20 we learn of this way Jesus initiated in us, for us, with us … all those implied dative prepositions. Sadly, the typical translation calls it a “new way”. The kind of “new” is that characteristic of a **freshly slain body…like a little lamb.** Think of Rev. 5:6, **“I saw a little lamb as slain, but standing.”** There is a governing nature of Jesus that **penetrates the veil,** taking us with Him like the High Priest wore the ephod on the breast.

And that is the kind of priest we have over God’s household / temple / house that He fills (Heb 10:21).

Thus, since He went in and penetrated the veil by His own fresh blood **with us borne on His breast,** we can come to interface with Him in the Holy of Holies (Heb 10:22). Heb 10:22 is sort of a restatement of Col 3:1-4 and Eph 2:6. The corporate risen body’s head is in heaven governing from the Right Hand and we are on earth connected by this “way”, this “slain Lamb,” “Christ-crucified” nature. It is this **“weakness of God”** that overcomes the “strength of men” (1Co 1-2). Thus, we are sprinkled clean **by Who He is,** not what we do.

Thus, in Heb 10:23 we are continually saying the same thing in the same place (confessing), retaining the same “Logos” = **the same underlying matrix that reckons how things are,** which can be a communication or **The Communication** as we see in Heb 1:3. If we maintain, the **“in Son”** thesis of Heb. 1:2 all the way through the book, then the Expectation is Christ in us! He is faithful!

Is this the same Expectation as in Heb 6:19? **Yes, the “in Son” theme fits each and every aspect of Hebrews.** He is our Expectation as the head we are to tightly lay hold of as the body (Col 2:19). Or as Heb 6:19 says it, the anchor of our soul life is Christ crucified, the slain little Lamb standing, Who went behind the curtain into the Holy of Holies.

Thus, the anchor of our soul is not that I have a “J-train ticket” when I die, but that **my soul has union right now** with Jesus as Head of a body-temple that we are spiritually being built into.

So is John sating the same thing in 1Jo 3:1-3? **Yes.** We are called **“children of God”** in1Jo 3:1, or as Hebrews 2:13 says it, **“the children and I”,** which refers to Heb 2:10’s, “many sons into glory”. The world system does not know us in this way because **it does not know Jesus in this way.**

Then in 1Jo 3:2, John declares we are **the sons of God** even though we look like other people to outsiders who see other people *only* by their senses. This is like what Paul said in 2Co 5:16, but in sort of an inverse way. Paul said **we do not know each other according to the flesh, nor do we know Jesus that way anymore.** Rather, because we are “in Christ”, a corporate risen body, **it is a new creature-creation** (2Co 5:17). A new creature as a new head – **back to the point Paul made in Col 2:19.**

Then John continues in 1Jo 3:2, when Jesus appears – **not known in the flesh** – but in this different way of the spirit, the we shall be like Him due to the fact that **we perceive Him “down exactly how” He is.** This again is like what Paul said in **2Co 3:18 about beholding as in a mirror and being transformed into the same Image.**  I think this is also the meaning of Heb 2:9, *which I have already noted has alignment with 1Jo 3:1-3 above.* You see, in the first part of Hebrews, the author(s) compare Jesus “as He is” with a bunch of **Bible characters that a Jew would be tempted to hold in higher esteem,** which includes angels. **“But we see Jesus…”** (Heb 2:9 KJV).
Thus, in 1Jo 3:3, everyone having **this expectation = Christ in you people being the expected glory cloud in His own temple** (Col 1:27) and **Christ our life appearing** (Col 3:4), then *we should* **let die those parts of this risen body that are earth bound** (Col 3:5). Again this is exactly what John is saying, but in sort of a reverse way, **“set yourself apart “down exactly how” He is set apart** or as KJV says it *“purifieth himself, even as he is pure.”*

The expectation of Jesus being the life of His body **naturally excludes my soul life expressions on earth.** In fact, Jesus always said this. No person can even be a disciple – cannot even follow – unless they ruin and destroy way, completely off, the soul-life. (Luke 9:23-26, Mat 10:37-39, etc.)
Why such harsh reality? 
Because Jesus designed-created our souls for His life-Image-Likeness. As Gen 1:26 has always said, **people are designed to bear God’s Image,** which we would have zero clue about, had it not been for Jesus coming to earth, going into kenosis (*self-emptying*), being that little lamb going to slaughter – that one Lamb that did when to the altar in Isa 53 while we all as sheep went astray. Jesus was obedient unto death on a cross. That is the kind of “new way” is the very kind that pierced the veil of flesh. It is how we know Him and how He is the anchor in any circumstance or situation on earth.

> So yes, all three Expectations – Hopes are all about Jesus simply
>   being the life in His risen, united body, the church.

Comment: Thank you it is a great explanation :-) Can we call Christ a Creature? Is he not he Creator? Are you refering to the Human aspect of Christ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Of course, Jesus is Creator God. The Greek word can mean either creation or creature. The reason why it would be OK to use creature is due to what happened at the cross, when we became "in Christ", dead to the old and alive to God in the Resurrection (Col 2:12, Rom 6, etc.). The "new creature" would simply be another way of speaking about the church with Christ as Head. Think of it like John 12:24. One lone seed went down and then a plant came up all connected to the seed-life = the risen body (Col 3:1, Eph 2:6).

Answer (score 0):

## Hebrews 4:14-16... *Jesus* is the high priest we hold on to for help

This is the most concise summary of what these verses are talking about.

**Hebrews 4:14–16 (LEB)**

> Therefore, because we have a great high priest who has gone through the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold fast to our confession. For we do not have a high priest who is not able to sympathize with our weaknesses, but who has been tempted in all things in the same way, without sin. Therefore let us approach with confidence to the throne of grace, in order that we may receive mercy and find grace to help in time of need.

"Hope" covers a wide, broad concept, not any one, single, small, detailed micro-teaching in particular. "Hope" refers to Jesus, but in many ways and on many levels, mainly Jesus work as Messiah.

"Hope" is not technical-theological jargon, referring to some specific thing like "sprint" is jargon for a "project manager" in the software world. "Hope" is a concept and can be referred to by its idea, even without the word. That said, both the concept and the word itself appear in enough places to answer your question. "Hope" is the idea of "confidently looking forward to something" is what they mean, thus anything with this theme in the Bible will somehow relate.

In a sense, Israel "hoped" in Moses as a kind of short-term Messiah from Egyptian captivity. Jesus is, in a sense, a kind of "super Moses" that Israel has been hoping for.

### Expansion:

- Heb 6:19 "enter in" is a reference to the high preist because he alone can "enter into" the holy of holies.
- God is our "refuge" or "hope" in time of need...

**Psalm 46:1 (LEB)**

> God is our refuge and strength, 
>   a very sufficient help in troubles.

- The word "hope" is more clearly indicated and defined in Jesus as the descendent of Jesse (David's father), explaining that in him (Jesus) the "nations/'gentiles'/(all people) will *hope*"...

**Romans 15:12 (LEB)**

> And again Isaiah says, 
>   “The root of Jesse will come, 
>   even the one who rises to rule over the Gentiles; 
>   in him the Gentiles will put their hope.”

*Note the word for "Geneiles" is the same as "nations"*

*The word "hope" here is "ἐλπιοῦσιν", a future verb, essentially the same word from your other references, 1Jn 3:3, Heb 10:23*

- Remember that Israel is looking for a Messiah, as John presumes, meaning that they "hope" for him to come...

**John 7:42 (LEB)**

> Has not the scripture said that the Christ comes from the descendants of David, and from Bethlehem, the village where David was?

- There is also hope for Jesus to bring even resurrection from death, as one of many things the New Testament community "hoped in" Jesus for as the Messiah...

**John 11:25 (LEB)**

> Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. The one who believes in me, even if he dies, will live,

**Philippians 3:10–11 (LEB)**

> so that I may know him and the power of his resurrection and the fellowship of his sufferings, being conformed to his death, if somehow I may attain to the resurrection from the dead.

- Other related verses...

**Luke 4:18–19 (LEB)**

> The Spirit of the Lord is upon me,  because of which he has anointed me  to proclaim good news to the poor.  He has sent me  to proclaim release to the captives,  and recovery of sight to the blind,  to send out in freedom those who are oppressed,  to proclaim the favorable year of the Lord.”

...Jesus is the one hoped for, which Isaiah's prophecy foretold, whom Israel was waiting for, to do these things.

**Hebrews 11:1 (LEB)**

> Now faith is the realization of what is hoped for, the proof of things not seen.

Hope is tied to faith, by New Testament imolication, that is Jesus, per Jn 3:16 and the rest of the New Testament. So, hope refers to the salvation from Jesus that comes by faith, including all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the “hope” talked about in Hebrews 10:23**

Hebrews 10:23  (NASB)

> 23 "Let us hold fast the confession of our hope(**of resurrection** )
>   without wavering, for He who promised is faithful."

The bold words " **of resurrection "** inserted in the verse  by me.

In the letter to His Hebrew brothers Paul implores  them to hold fast the confession of our hope without wavering. He advises them  to stimulate one  another to love and to express publicly their hope,talking about it, makes it real and vivid , making hope a strong anchor  for the soul. Paul wrote:

Hebrews 6:19  (NASB)

> "This hope we have as an anchor of the soul, a hope both sure and
>   steadfast and one which enters [b]within the veil."

Paul compares the anchor of the ship  which holds  it firm to ride out  the storms,instead of being tossed about ,like wise hope gives  strength to ride out the hardships of life, and keep  one spiritually, mentally and emotionally staple,Therefore  Christians must strive hard to keep hope alive, because this hope cannot be seen.

Romans 8:24-25 (NASB)

> 24" For in hope we have been saved, but hope that is seen is not hope;
>   for who hopes for what he already sees"
>
> 25" But if we hope for what we do not see, with perseverance we wait
>   eagerly for it."